# Setting a breakpoint in a stripped binary with LLDB

Tags: macos, frameworks, lldb

I'm trying to debug an obscure issue with a closed-source command line tool on macOS, and (with some disassembly) it appears that the bug is in a framework it's using. I'd like to confirm the issue, so I fired up LLDB and tried to set a breakpoint in one of the methods in the framework–however, I'm not really sure how to (LLDB can't find the method when I tell it to break, and I can't stop at a memory location either). Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get LLDB to debug the framework's code?

EDIT: It seems like the issue is not with the framework, but the fact that it is stripped. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what you tried, and the symbol name you are trying to break on?  It's hard to speculate about what's going wrong otherwise.

Comment: A bit more detail: I'm having an issue with Location Services on my Mac (I'm not able to enable it). I was hoping that class-dump+LLDB could shed some light on the issue. Running System Preferences in LLDB, I try to attach to methods that sound promising, but `b -[SomeClass someSelector]` doesn't work, as the the code is in Preference Pane or Framework, not in the main binary so LLDB doesn't find it. Using `rbreak someSelector` finds the method and puts a breakpoint there, but the breakpoint isn't activated when it should.

Comment: Sounds like what you are trying should work.  What does "break list" say after you've set the breakpoints in this way?  BTW, for future reference, if you want to break on all instances of a particular selector, you can say "break set -S someSelector", though that shouldn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: @JimIngham It appears like I can't set any breakpoints at all anymore, no matter how I try to set it (`break`, `break set -S`, `rbreak`, etc.) LLDB just spits out `WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.`

Comment: Note that if you set a breakpoint in a framework that hasn't been loaded yet (e.g. if you set it before you run and the framework isn't directly loaded into your program) the breakpoint will initially say it was unable to resolve to any actual locations, but lldb keeps re-resolving the breakpoint in any new libraries that get loaded.  Maybe that explains what you are seeing?

Comment: You can use the "image list" command to see what libraries are currently loaded in your program.

Comment: Huh, I'm seeing this behavior occur with the main app binary as well. In fact, all my breakpoints seem to be hitting random frameworks such as `AppKit` and `UIFoundation`–things I *don't* want to debug. `image list` shows the binaries I want to debug loaded.

Comment: At this point it's probably best to file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com describing the problem.

Comment: @JimIngham Apparently the binary was stripped and I didn't realize it, which is why LLDB couldn't find any symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I finally realized that the framework that I was working with didn't have debugging symbols (doh!), which is why LLDB couldn't find anything. Working with stripped binaries takes a bit more work, and Apple [Technical Note 2239](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION28) goes over using the Objective-C runtime to set breakpoints. Here's the example code translated to LLDB the best I could:

```
$ lldb /Applications/TextEdit.app
(lldb) target create "/Applications/TextEdit.app"
Current executable set to '/Applications/TextEdit.app' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 2463 launched: '/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit' (x86_64)
Process 2463 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x437c7a, 0x00007fffea1603ba libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffea1603ba libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
->  0x7fffea1603ba <+10>: ret
    0x7fffea1603bb <+11>: nop

libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_overwrite_trap:
    0x7fffea1603bc <+0>:  mov    r10, rcx
    0x7fffea1603bf <+3>:  mov    eax, 0x1000020
(lldb) # Try to find the
(lldb) # -[DocumentController openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:] 
(lldb) # symbol.
(lldb) break set -S openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:
Breakpoint 1: where = AppKit`-[NSDocumentController openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:], address = 0x00007fffd21d244f
(lldb) # These are not the droids we're looking for. It turns out that 
(lldb) # TextEdit ships with its symbols stripped, so we'll have to do 
(lldb) # this the hard way.
(lldb) #
(lldb) # Get the Class object for the DocumentController class.
(lldb) expr -- void *$class = (void *)objc_getClass("DocumentController")
(lldb) # Get the SEL object for the "openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:" method.
(lldb) expr -- void *$sel=(void *)sel_getUid("openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:")
(lldb) # Get a pointer to the method implementation.
(lldb) po (void*)class_getMethodImplementation($class, $sel)
0x0000000100006df4
(lldb) # Set a breakpoint on the method.
(lldb) b 0x0000000100006df4
Breakpoint 2: where = TextEdit`___lldb_unnamed_symbol74$$TextEdit, address = 0x0000000100006df4
(lldb) # Resume execution, and then create a new, untitled document.
(lldb) c
Process 2463 resuming
Process 2463 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x437c7a, 0x0000000100006df4 TextEdit`___lldb_unnamed_symbol74$$TextEdit, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100006df4 TextEdit`___lldb_unnamed_symbol74$$TextEdit
TextEdit`___lldb_unnamed_symbol74$$TextEdit:
->  0x100006df4 <+0>: push   rbp
    0x100006df5 <+1>: mov    rbp, rsp
    0x100006df8 <+4>: push   r15
    0x100006dfa <+6>: push   r14
```